# How to make check in flat list if data is not coming in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to perform checks if the data is not coming in the flat list form the server  in my case if data is coming it is working perfectly but when there is no data it is showing error here is my code

this is my flat list now i want to perform checks on it...

```
<FlatList
          data={this.state.fetchJobs}
          keyExtractor={(a, b) => b.toString()}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              activeOpacity={0.9}
              onPress={() =>
                this.props.navigation.navigate("DetailJobScreen", {
                  job_id: item.job_id
                })
              }
            >
              <CompleteJobLayout
                Completejobname={`${entities.decode(item.employer_name)}`}
                featuredCompleteJobColor={`${entities.decode(
                  item.featured_color
                )}`}
                imageUriCompleteJobfeatured={{ uri: `${item.featured_url}` }}
                Completejobtitle={`${entities.decode(item.project_title)}`}
                jobflagimageUri={{ uri: `${item.location.flag}` }}
                Completejoblevel={`${entities.decode(
                  item.project_level.level_title
                )}`}
                Completejobcountry={`${entities.decode(
                  item.location._country
                )}`}
                Completejobrate={`${entities.decode(item.project_cost)}`}
                fav_job_user_id={item.job_id}
                Fav_Color={`${entities.decode(item.favorit)}`}
                Completejobduration={`${entities.decode(
                  item.project_duration
                )}`}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
        />
```

here is the response when data is comming...

```
[
  {
    "favorit": "",
    "featured_url": "",
    "featured_color": "",
    "location": {
      "_country": "India",
      "flag": "https://amentotech.com/projects/api_workreap/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/img-03-2.png"
    },
    "job_id": 178,
    "job_link": "https://amentotech.com/projects/api_workreap/project/forest-technology-professor/",
    "_is_verified": "yes",
    "project_level": {
      "level_title": "Medium Level",
      "level_sign": 0
    },
    "project_type": "Fixed",
    "project_duration": "01 to 03 months",
    "project_cost": "&#36;6,399.00",
    "attanchents": [
      {
        "document_name": "WordPress customization",
        "file_size": "85.84 KB",
        "filetype": {
          "ext": "pdf",
          "type": "application/pdf"
        },
        "extension": "",
        "url": "https://amentotech.com/projects/worktern/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/WordPress-customization.pdf"
      },
      {
        "document_name": "How to run mysql command in database",
        "file_size": "16.06 KB",
        "filetype": {
          "ext": "docx",
          "type": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
        },
        "extension": "",
        "url": "https://amentotech.com/projects/worktern/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/How-to-run-mysql-command-in-database.docx"
      }
    ],
    "skills": [
      {
        "skill_link": "https://amentotech.com/projects/api_workreap/skill/c/",
        "skill_name": "C++"
      },
      {
        "skill_link": "https://amentotech.com/projects/api_workreap/skill/graphic-design/",
        "skill_name": "Graphic Design"
      },
      {
        "skill_link": "https://amentotech.com/projects/api_workreap/skill/html-5/",
        "skill_name": "HTML 5"
      },
      {
        "skill_link": "https://amentotech.com/projects/api_workreap/skill/seo/",
        "skill_name": "SEO"
      }
    ],
    "employer_name": "Steven Ford",
    "project_title": "Forest Technology Professor",
    "project_content": "Some Data"
  }]
```

and this is the response when there is  no data available...

```
[
  {
    "type": "error",
    "message": "Some error occur, please try again later"
  }
]
```

and this is my function where i am fetching data...

```
 fetchCompleteJobData = async () => {
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    const response = await fetch(
      "https:...//listing/get_jobs?listing_type=company&company_id=" +
      params.employ_id
    );
    const json = await response.json();
    this.setState({ fetchJobs: json, isLoading: false });
    console.log('These are my jobs'+JSON.stringify(fetchJobs))
  };
```

Kindly tell me how can i make check if there is no data show no data message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if response is of type `error` and set an empty array in your component's state.

```
fetchCompleteJobData = async () => {
  //... your code to fetch data

  const json = await response.json();
  if(Array.isArray(json) && json[0] && json[0].type && json[0].type === 'error') {
    this.setState({ fetchJobs:[], isLoading: false }); // empty data set 
  } else {
    this.setState({ fetchJobs: json, isLoading: false });
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks it worked ... kindly tell me if i want to show a message that "No data available" how can i do it in FlatList

Comment: `FlatList` provides [`ListEmptyComponent `](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#listemptycomponent) prop to pass in a placeholder component to show when list is empty. You can use this prop to set a component containing `Text` to show your error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
this.state.fetchJobs.length ? (
    <FlatList
        ...
    />
) : (
    <View>
        ...
    </View>
)
}
```